# Is a C++ function that catches all exceptions inside it "noexcept"?

Tags: c++

A have a conceptual question. Consider a C++ function that catches all possible exceptions thrown **by code it calls**, it looks like

```
void func() {
    try {
        // lots of stuff that may throw
    } catch(...) {
        // handle exceptions, NOTHING here throws.
    }
}
```

My question is: Does this function qualifies as `noexcept`? And should it be declared as such? I have this doubt because there is a possible exception propagation going on inside it, but caller code will never receive one.

Comment: Does it quallify: Maybe; depends on the code in the `catch` handler.  If the catch handler throws and you mark the function as `noexcept` then terminal will be called.

Comment: Richard, No `catch() {}` does not throw. This is why in not sure if this `func` is `nothrow`

Comment: A great read concerning noexcept is this blog post: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/noexcept-what-for/ Also see historical motivation: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2855.html#problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Exception specifications, Section 15.4/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/except.spec#12) of the C++11 standard:

> A function with a non-throwing exception-specification does not allow any exceptions.

If the code in the `catch` block is guaranteed to not throw any exceptions, then the function can have a non-throwing exception-specification. i.e. you may use:

```
void func() throw () { ... }
```

or

```
void func() noexcept { ... }
```

or

```
void func() noexcept(true) { ... }
```

Comment: This is not that explicit for me. So you mean, as long as it does not delegate any exception handling to the caller it is eligible to the declared `nothrow`, right?

Comment: @ElvisTeixeira, that is my understanding.